# Не удаляется элемент

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Добрый день.

Ребят, подскажите, битый час сижу не могу понять, в чем проблема.

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $('body').find('form:not(this)').children('label').removeClass('red');
    var answer = checkForm($(this).parent().get(0));
    if(answer != false)
    {
        var result = $(this).siblings('.email').children('input').val();
        $('.results').append('<div class="result">'+ result +'</div>');
        $('.result').append('<div class="close_btn"></div>')
        console.log(result);
        // $('body').remove(); //тут написать, если мейл правильный
    }
    });
    $('.close_btn').click(function() {
        $(this).parent('.result').remove();
});
```

Суть в том, что если я сам в html запишу див с классом result и внутри него класс close_btn, то все замечательно работает. А вот если .result и close_btn генерируются js-ом, то уже не работает. В чем проблема?

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!!

Comment: @Александр Котов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте написать функцию нажатия вот так:
`$('body').on('click', '.close_btn', function() {});`